# Youtube API V3 and PHP: How to update syndicate option through API

Tags: php, youtube-api, google-api-php-client, youtube-data-api

I am using YouTube API V3 and [Google API PHP client](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client) to upload video. I am not able to find any parameter to update syndicate option which is in advanced settings.

In V2 the option is available with the parameter "syndicate" in access controls. But in V3 I am not able to find.

Can any one help me on this? Thanks in advance.

Note: I am using a publisher account which have access to the syndication options.

Comment: Check this in google group link https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=6432

Comment: Check out this link.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17384489/youtube-ios-sdk-correct-gtlqueryyoutube-parameters-to-filter-out-videos-which-c

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17384489/youtube-ios-sdk-correct-gtlqueryyoutube-parameters-to-filter-out-videos-which-c